# What is a good git practice for working on multiple files over multiple days before pushing

Tags: git

I have a project that requires editing/coding of multiple files which take up multiple days to finish. By the end of each day, I will end up with unfinished changes in multiple files that need to be continue the next day.

My current workflow is that before I can make a final PR, each time I commit to the same commit (first commit --> push, then git amend --> force push). When I finish the task, I reset that huge commit and then break it into multiple small commits. Then I make my PR.

However, I am not sure if this is a good workflow but I am not too sure how to improve. The best way would still be have a clear executable plan and follow it through task by task. However, my personal work style that I prefer to be a bit more spontaneous and jump from place to place quickly.

What would be your git workflow when working with a larger task that for some reason just have to span through several days and make a big PR rather than breaking into smaller ones? Please advice.

Comment: Decades of research and experience have led to practices you reject because they dno't suit your "personal work style", yet you want advice on how to improve your workflow?  Don't really know what to say to that.

Comment: You should be squashing commits, rather than amending the same commit over and over. Even if you commit sloppily at first, if you're a perfectionist, you can go back and edit your history with git rebase -i.

Comment: @MatthewHinea, yeah that is a good point. I should do that instead,

Comment: @MatthewHinea But actually squash go in sequence. So what if I did a commit1 about topic A, commit2 about B, then commit3 back to A changing something. How can I squash c1, c3 together but leave c2?

Comment: @J_yang you can easily do that via the git rebase interface. Just reorder the lines. In this case, move the c3 line to after c1 and change "pick" to "squash"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be squashing commits, rather than amending the same commit over and over. Even if you commit sloppily at first, if you're a perfectionist, you can go back and edit your history with `git rebase -i`.

This is what it would look like with 3 commits where you want the 3rd squashed into the first. When you first run `git rebase -i` it will show you something like this:

```
pick some_hash1 1st change
pick some_hash2 2nd change
pick some_hash3 3rd change
```

Edit that file so that it shows this:

```
pick some_hash1 1st change
squash some_hash3 3rd change
pick some_hash2 2nd change
```

Then close it. You may have to do some fixup and run `git add -A && git rebase --continue` but it's pretty intuitive.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  I start using squashing. :)

Comment: This is exactly the point I didn't know that we can rearrange commits like this.